# REGEX to match "Track " but not if followed by 2 numbers

Tags: regex

What I need is the regex equivalent of this statement:

match **"Artist - Album (Year) (Track** , but only if there are 2 digits after the space.

I have no idea how/if that can be done. I have labored over this for too long and I'm sorry if I've missed something simple, but I did try to find the answer before resorting to asking for help. It's how I got as far as I did, which as a non coder is probably elementery.

**Here is my scenario and what I've tried:**

```
"Artist - Album (Year) (Track 01).mp3"
"Artist - Album (Year) (Track 2).mp3"
...
"Artist - Album (Year) (Track 10).mp3"
```

Match:

```
".*\(track
```

Replace:

```
track
```

**Here's what it does:**

```
track01).mp3"
track2).mp3"
...
track10).mp3"
```

Basically, it matches everything starting with **open quote upto and including (Track space**. It works great for that. Note, there may be some important stuff before the open quotes I need to preserve. So the first quote is important as the beginning of the match.

However, if I replace with **track**, it will leave me with **track#** for any line without 2 digits after the match. All of them need 2 digits (track08, track09, track10 and so on). So I need a way to match **"Artist - Album (Year) (Track** , but only if there are 2 digits after the space. This way it will ignore lines that don't meet that condition and I can replace them with **track0** in  the next step, but specifying the number of digits after the space as 1.

What I don't want to do is loose those digits. I have been able to match only the lines containing 2 digits, but it also matches those 2 digits and replaces them. That wont work, I need them!

**Here's what I want (which I don't mind accomplishing in steps):**

```
track01.mp3
track02.mp3
...
track10.mp3
```

Please note that I am an amateur. I have no idea what a positive lookahead assertion is, or what ever jargon used to explain a solution means. Please excuse my ignorance, I am trying.

Comment: Maybe `re.findall(r'.*\((track\s+\d+)', re.sub(r'(".*\(track\s+)(\d)\b', r'\g<1>0\2', s))`

Comment: You need to match all the digits, then format the track string in a callback function. Why mess around doing it any other way ?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that maybe we would start with an expression such as,

```
.*\(track\s+([0-9]{2})\)(\S+)
```

and our desired two digits boundary is in this capturing group: `([0-9]{2})`

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/oChy1H/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Lol...after I mentioned I don't know what a positive look ahead assertion was, I looked it up and discovered it's what I needed. I tried adding `(?=\d{2})` and playing around with it a bit to get something that worked. It figures, Stumbled upon a solution just after asking...murphy's law.

`".*track.(?=\d{2})` worked, but thanks to the suggestions I found `.*track\s+(?=\d{2})` is superior, as it catches more than one white space character.

Thanks you for the quick and non judgmental feedback.

Answer (score 0):

If you choose to do it in 2 passes, it could be done like this.

Pass 1:

Find `(?i)".*?Track[ \t]*(\d)(?!\d).*?(\.\w+).*?"`
Replace `Track0$1$2`

https://regex101.com/r/pLCog5/1

Pass 2:

Find `(?i)".*?Track[ \t]*(\d\d)(?!\d).*?(\.\w+).*?"`
Replace `Track$1$2`

https://regex101.com/r/wh8PmX/1